# Creating a table in pandas from json

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am really stuck in creating a table from nested json. The json output from a Coinmarketcap API request:

`data = {'status': {'timestamp': '2020-05-05T21:34:45.057Z', 'error_code': 0, 'error_message': None, 'elapsed': 8, 'credit_count': 1, 'notice': None}, 'data': {'1': {'urls': {'website': ['https://bitcoin.org/'], 'technical_doc': ['https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf'], 'twitter': [], 'reddit': ['https://reddit.com/r/bitcoin'], 'message_board': ['https://bitcointalk.org'], 'announcement': [], 'chat': [], 'explorer': ['https://blockchain.coinmarketcap.com/chain/bitcoin', 'https://blockchain.info/', 'https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/', 'https://blockchair.com/bitcoin', 'https://explorer.viabtc.com/btc'], 'source_code': ['https://github.com/bitcoin/']}, 'logo': 'https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png', 'id': 1, 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'symbol': 'BTC', 'slug': 'bitcoin', 'description': 'Bitcoin (BTC) is a consensus network that enables a new payment system and a completely digital currency. Powered by its users, it is a peer to peer payment network that requires no central authority to operate. On October 31st, 2008, an individual or group of individuals operating under the pseudonym "Satoshi Nakamoto" published the Bitcoin Whitepaper and described it as: "a purely peer-to-peer version of electronic cash, which would allow online payments to be sent directly from one party to another without going through a financial institution."', 'notice': None, 'date_added': '2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'tags': ['mineable'], 'tag-names': ['Mineable'], 'tag-groups': ['APPLICATION'], 'is_hidden': 0, 'platform': None, 'category': 'coin'}, '2': {'urls': {'website': ['https://litecoin.org/'], 'technical_doc': [], 'twitter': ['https://twitter.com/LitecoinProject'], 'reddit': ['https://reddit.com/r/litecoin'], 'message_board': ['https://litecointalk.io/', 'https://litecoin-foundation.org/'], 'announcement': ['https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=47417.0'], 'chat': ['https://telegram.me/litecoin'], 'explorer': ['https://blockchair.com/litecoin', 'https://chainz.cryptoid.info/ltc/', 'http://explorer.litecoin.net/chain/Litecoin', 'https://ltc.tokenview.com/en', 'https://explorer.viabtc.com/ltc'], 'source_code': ['https://github.com/litecoin-project/litecoin']}, 'logo': 'https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/2.png', 'id': 2, 'name': 'Litecoin', 'symbol': 'LTC', 'slug': 'litecoin', 'description': 'Litecoin is a peer-to-peer cryptocurrency created by Charlie Lee. It was created based on the Bitcoin protocol but differs in terms of the hashing algorithm used. Litecoin uses the memory intensive Scrypt proof of work mining algorithm. Scrypt allows consumer-grade hardware such as GPU to mine those coins.', 'notice': None, 'date_added': '2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z', 'tags': ['mineable'], 'tag-names': ['Mineable'], 'tag-groups': ['APPLICATION'], 'is_hidden': 0, 'platform': None, 'category': 'coin'}}}`

the code:

```
result = pd.json_normalize(data,'data',['website'], errors='ignore')
print(result)
```

the output:

```
0     website
0  1  NaN
1  2  NaN
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like that:

```
0     website
0  1  https://bitcoin.org/
1  2  https://litecoin.org/
```

I've tried so many things and really frustrated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `json_normalize` isn't perfect, you might have to transform the data beforehand.

Comment: thanks for the input. what is meant by transforming it? Thanks

Comment: Change how that dictionary is organized, extract certain parts of the data and create a new one, etc.

Comment: i think Allen answered ur question, unless there is more u want, in which case, u need to edit ur question, or ask a new one

Comment: @AMC thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to massage the data a little bit to get what you want.

```
(
    pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
    .loc['urls']
    .apply(lambda x: x['website'][0])
    .to_frame('website')
)

    website
1   https://bitcoin.org/
2   https://litecoin.org/
```

To get technical_doc, you can do something similar. The reason you got error is because for some elements there is no tech doc.

```
(
    pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
    .loc['urls']
    .apply(lambda x: (x['technical_doc']+[''])[0])
    .to_frame('website')
)
```

To get logo, you need to loc 'logo' instead of 'urls' as it's at the same level as 'urls'

```
(
    pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
    .loc['logo']
    .to_frame('logo')
)
```

Comment: thanks! but if I want other data like: pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
(   
.loc['urls']
    .apply(lambda x: x['technical_doc'][0])
    .to_frame('technical_doc')
)

it is outputs an error list index out of range

Comment: @RamboJ, I have added an example.

Comment: Allen thanks again. when I try to get 'logo' and use that:

(
    pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
    .loc['logo']
    .apply(lambda x: (x['logo']+[''])[0])
    .to_frame('logo')
)

I run into this issue: "string indices must be integers"

I am probably hopeless at programming...

Comment: @RamboJ, 'logo' didn't work because it's at the same level as 'urls', not 'websites'. I've given you an example.

Comment: I did it awhile ago, but coz I have less than 15 reputation -> my votes aren't publicly displayed...